# Django Post Office - How can I add a foreign key in the Email model that references the Client model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-postoffice

I'm utilizing the django-post-office library in my Django project. I aim to link the library's existing Email model to my Client model, ensuring that while a single client can have multiple emails, each email can only be linked to one client. Is this feasible? Interestingly, ChatGPT provided a solution, but it mentioned parameters (create_models, model_class) that don't exist in the library therefore the code below doesn’t work. However, I'm curious if ChatGPT might have been hinting at an approach I am not aware. Suggestions how to solve it ?

```
from post_office.models import Email as PostOfficeEmail

class ClientEmail(PostOfficeEmail):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emails')

from post_office import mail

def send_client_email(client, subject, message):
    mail.send(
        recipients=[client.email],
        sender='your_sender_email@example.com',
        subject=subject,
        message=message,
        create_models=True,  # This will create an Email model instance
        model_class=ClientEmail,  # Use our extended model
    )
    # Associate the email with the client
    email = ClientEmail.objects.last()
    email.client = client
    email.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you can use to add a foreign key in the Email model that references the Client model using the django-post-office library:

```py
from django.db import models
from post_office.models import Email as PostOfficeEmail
from post_office import mail

class Client(models.Model):
    # Your Client model fields here

class ClientEmail(PostOfficeEmail):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emails')

def send_client_email(client, subject, message):
    email = ClientEmail.objects.create(
        client=client,
        subject=subject,
        message=message,
        from_email='your_sender_email@example.com',
        to=[client.email],
    )
    mail.send(email)
```

This code creates a `ClientEmail` model that inherits from `PostOfficeEmail` and adds a foreign key to the `Client` model. The `send_client_email` function creates a new `ClientEmail` instance associated with the specified client and sends the email using the `mail.send` function from the django-post-office library.